# How to catch keyboard response in Telegram

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

```
bot.onText(/Pizza/, (msg) => {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "OK, " + msg.from.first_name + ". What kind of pizza?", {
        "reply_markup": {
            "keyboard": [["Peperoni", "4 cheese", "Vegetarian", "Tomato"]],
            "resize_keyboard": true
        }
    });
});

bot.onText(/Peperoni/, (msg) => {
    console.log(msg.text);
    if (msg.text === "Peperoni") {
        console.log("Entered IF");
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Peperoni is there " + msg.from.first_name + ".Choose the quantity", {
            "reply_markup": {
                "keyboard": [["1", "2", "3"]],
                "resize_keyboard": true
            }
        })
        console.log(msg.text);
    }
});
```

Using node telegram bot api, my code is above. I can catch Peperoni, when user presses Peperoni, but how do I catch the quantity which I ask later. Trying to insert the last `console.log` at all the places, but this never happens. Any ideas please ;)

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to save the last user request into a database table or a file for the `chat_id` and then get the quantity. You can retrieve the pizza type anytime from the table or the file for the chat_id

[image]

In the picture above you can see I save chat_id of every user making a request. I also save the `request_type`. In you case you can have `request_value` and save the value as `pepperoni`. Then in the next request get the pizza count `1` and fetch the previous value from `request_value` field for the same `chat_id`

Comment: thanks! Do U happen to have any examples? Or what should I read to do so. I'm all new to databases.

Comment: I have it in PHP is that fine?

Comment: yes, completely. I'll try to implement it since there is mysql node packet as far as I found

Comment: Check my updated answer. Pasting code would not fit in here because I use authentication

Comment: Thanks, got the idea, will try to do so ;)

Answer (score 0):

**All incomming messages to bot are an object** :
(`text`, `voice`, `video` and ...)

**For example User Selected**: 1

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log(msg.text);
});
```

**Console Output:** // 1